# The best way to call onload function for android in phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova

How can I call to Onload function when the app is run on device?
On browser this line ...  working well, but when I run my app on android device the onLoad function not calling, 
whan can I do to make the `onload` call?

I have tried to add this code in the  tag inside of the `"<body onload="onLoad">... </body>"` code :

```
     <head>
              // ....
          <script>
            document.addEventListener('deviceready', onLoad);
          </script>
         <script type="text/javascript" src="js/help.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
```

help.js:

```
function onLoad()
{
   window.alert("onLoad");
}
```

onLoad- is the function that I write in my help.js file, and I add this file inside script tag. 
On my android device nothing the alert not show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`window.alert` works in browser and not in android.

you should use `notification.alert` as explained [here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-dialogs/index.html)

Comment: I have some window.alert in my code, and its work fine, I don't know if it will help.... sorry

Comment: You need to understand the philosophy of phonegap

Comment: I'm new in phonegap, maybe you have sume link to more information about phonegap developing for android? (untill now I worked on eclipse with java for android )

Comment: Read to understand how phonegap works https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/overview/index.html

Comment: I'm marking your answer before trying it, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Unclear from your snippet but you may need to include cordova.js in your HTML body in a script tag if you aren't doing so already.  Cordova CLI will make sure that file gets to where it needs to be when building for a device:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
```